# Excel > Exclude a named range from COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, countif, named-ranges

I've got a spreadsheet with hundred of rows, each with a unique ID and each designated to a person.
On a different tab is a summary sheet where my formula goes (count of IDs for each person). On a third sheet, I have a named range 'excludes' which has certain IDs included in a single column.

i.e my sheet1 has:

```
ID  Name
1   Bob
2   Bob
3   Bob
4   Shirley
5   Ted
6   Michael
```

The named range has say IDs, 2 and 3 in it, so I want my COUNTIFS to return the value 1 for Bob.

```
ID
2
3
```

Here's my formula but I think I'm missing something:
`=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A:A,'summary'!$A1,'Sheet1!A:A,"<>excludes")`

I want to exclude every ID in the excludes named range from my COUNTIFS result.
Do I need to use sumproduct or something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To be clear, you'd want `1`, but also `4`, `5`, `6` correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B7=D2)*(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A7,excludes,0))))
```

[image]

---

If you want countifs then you will need to count the whole and subtract where it exists in the named range:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,D2)-SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B:B,D2,A:A,excludes))
```

[image]